# What is the best approach to load jQuery modules using webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, npm, webpack

I have some project written in PHP, and now I want do use webpack, npm etc. to manage a front-end resources.

Until now I copy-paste sources of the JS/CSS files into a public directory and simply include these at the page.

I have file e.g.: `client.js` which contains:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > ($(window).height() / 3)) {
            $(".return-to-top").fadeIn(200);
        } else {
            $(".return-to-top").fadeOut(200);
        }
    });

    $('.return-to-top').click(function () {
        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 500);
        return false;
    });

    $('pre code').each(function (i, block) {
        if (!$(block).attr("class")) {
            $(block).addClass('text');
        }
        hljs.highlightBlock(block);
    });
});
```

As you can see, in this snippet I use jQuery, hljs plugin (I have more that kind of the files with a different plugins inside).

Try to configure npm `package.json`:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "highlight.js": "^9.12.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
    "webpack": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.11"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

And `webpack.conf.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './resources/app.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/dist')
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['public/dist']),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
        })
    ]
};
```

`./resources/app.js`

```
import $ from "jquery";
import returnToTop from "./return-to-top";
import highlight from "./highlight";

window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;

$(function () {
    returnToTop($);
    highlight($);
});
```

And in the `return-to-top.js` and `highlight.js` files I have fragments of code from `client.js`.

`highlight.js`:

```
import hljs from "highlight.js";

export default function highlight() {
    $('pre code').each(function (i, block) {
        if (!$(block).attr("class")) {
            $(block).addClass('text');
        }
        hljs.highlightBlock(block);
    });
};
```

`return-to-top.js`:

```
export default function returnToTop() {
    $(document).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > ($(window).height() / 3)) {
            $(".return-to-top").fadeIn(200);
        } else {
            $(".return-to-top").fadeOut(200);
        }
    });

    $('.return-to-top').click(function () {
        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 500);
        return false;
    });
};
```

Some questions:

1. Is this a good approach?
2. Can I do this better? Especially handlers for click/scroll etc.
3. How can I efficiently include CSS?
4. Some good practices for "new guy in the town"?

I want to prepare my code for use a Vuejs.

Comment: I think you need to split this up into different questions, as specific as possible.

Comment: @jmb.mage in this post only question about CSS is not in the context, rest of the questions are connected.

Comment: It makes sense to have the files return-to-top.js and highlight.js? You can put the functions in one file and export them.

Answer (score 2):

> This is a good approach?

This looks like a pretty good starting point. I'd suggest to just try it: transpile / bundle your code and run it. If you come across errors, go from there, one error at a time.

> Can I do this better? Especially handlers for click/scroll etc.

Possibly. But runtime things like click/scroll handlers are kind of unrelated to the question about how to transition to ES modules, which is what you're actually doing.

> How can I efficiently include CSS?

I think there's not much of a change necessary here. Apart from the probability that you will be using webpack's [css-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/) to get your css to the desired public path, in the end you'll just end up with some CSS files that are loaded through `<link>` tags.

> Some good practices for "new guy in the town"?

Rock on :)

---

**Edit from comments**

> Can you provide more details about: *I'd suggest to just try it: transpile / bundle your code and run it?*

This sounds harder than it is; transpiling / bundling is the process webpack takes care of.

- Run a `webpack` command from the terminal to start a build using your webpack config file.
- Load the generated assets into a page, and just see if it works.

Comment: Can you provide more details about:  _I'd suggest to just try it: transpile / bundle your code and run it_?

Comment: Code is working. I was edited my post and provide a working example, so I can assume, that a transpile working?

Comment: Yes, if the code works, you've completed your objective: It works with webpack, and you're already using npm modules (`$`, `highlightjs`). Loading Vue in this environment should not be any problem also :)